# If $a,b>1$ then there is an integer $N$ such that $a^N>b$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Let $a,b>1$ be real numbers. I need to prove that there exists an integer $N>0$ such that $a^N>b.$ This seems like trivial by intuition but I can't have a rigorous proof. There's also a hint:  $(1+c)^N \geq 1 + Nc$.

Comment: Another hint: $c=a-1$.

Comment: Using the hint, this is not very hard. So: Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c = a - 1$, then $(1 + c)^N = a^N \ge 1 + Nc$

Let $b$ be any real number bigger than one.

We have $a^N = (1 + c)^N \ge 1 + Nc > Nc = b$

So let's get $N = \frac{b}{a - 1}$